# Excel problem for beginners: #REF! Error When referenced Row is deleted or Added

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ref

I have data in column A which is copied in another random location. The copied data could also be in column B-Z, AA... Etc, Or alternatively could be on a new sheet by setting the column `=Sheet1!A1` for example.

In the attached image I initially had a,b,c...through to f.
In this example,data is copied in the same column just further down by entering at `A10 =A1` and copying down as required.

[image]

When what was A5 is deleted as a row to remove 'e' you can see that `A14` now has the #REF! Error. This is strange to me because although the row is deleted the data has shifted up one. so `A14=A5` which previously returned 'e' should now return 'f' but instead returns the error. Initially I thought that this is because the data is in the same column but the same error is returned if on another sheet for example If I set `A1=Sheet1!A1` and then delete a row on `sheet1`.

If you drag down the copying formula again the error is corrected But surely this can be made to happen automatically? Especially if dealing with large amounts of data.

Surprisingly this error doesn't seem to have an obvious solution posted online.  I wanted to create this post for anyone to suggest feasible solutions for those starting out with excel (including myself).

Comment: You can use `=INDEX(A:A,1)` and continue the count from there. In Microsoft365 you may even use `SEQUENCE()` to parse an array of numbers to `INDEX()`.

Comment: Okay that works, but say I want to Add a bunch of rows to the end of the data. Is there a way to include this in the Index automatically? In many ways I think this question could be asked as: If I create an array of data, is it possible to mimic this array exactly regardless of what you do to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do here I'm afraid.

Comment: So I have 'a' though to 'h' in column A. How can I mimic this somewhere else in excel. So say if I delete row 2 to remove b, or add letters i,j,k in cells A18,19,20. Is it possible to create column which will mimic column A regardless of what I do.

Comment: Like this `=IF(A:A="","",A:A)`? Obviously don't use that anywhere in the `A:A` column itself.

Comment: Hm I'm not sure Im asking this question in the right way. Let me have a think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228412/discussion-between-inick1-and-jvdv).

Comment: What is the result you are expecting? `a,b,c,d,f,f,g,h` or `a,b,c,d,f,g,h`?

Comment: The latter. I seemed to have solved this now just selecting a Range i.e. =A1:A7 but please feel free to add any further methods as its interesting to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a general formula like `=A5` then you will face this issue. Excel is not built to handle this internally.

The best way to avoid this error is to use the `OFFSET` function. This function is dynamic so it will update when cells are added or deleted.

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: Hi So Ive put in =OFFSET(A1,0,0) and this returns A,B,C etc when dragging down but again when I delete a row above I get the ref error

Answer (score 0):

Setting the column to a range instead of =A1 and drag down, this seems to solve all problems.

e.g. =A1:A7 will return a-h but also if a row is then deleted/inserted the formula adapts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

### Avoid #REF

- The best way I found (so far) is the following formula in cell `A10`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$9,ROW(A10)-ROW(A$10)+1),"")
  ```
- You can delete any or all except two rows. Two rows are necessary for the range `A$1:A$9` to work. If you would leave only one row, the range would be `A$1:A$1` and could not be increased anymore.
- You can insert new rows before the last row (`9`). If you insert a row after the last row (`9`), it will not be affected by the formula.